# Protect Classic ASP Page within an ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, security, asp-classic

I would like to restrict access to a classic asp page that is contained within an ASP.NET application that uses Forms Authentication.

Is there a way to configure forms authentication so that it will restrict access to these pages?  I have the following in my web.config.

```
<location>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

I am running in 'classic' pipeline mode and I don't have the option of switching to 'integrated'.

Comment: Restrict how? Don't load it, make it read only? Please explain what you mean by restrict.

Comment: It would be nice if unauthorized access was re-directed to the loginUrl specified in the forms authentication part of the web.config

Comment: How are you embedding the ASP pages? Server.Execute?

Comment: The legacy classic asp page is contained in various directories throughout the application.

Comment: So the classic ASP pages are NOT embedded in ASP.NET pages? There are just classic ASP pages in the application? Sorry for asking so many questions; just trying to understand your setup.

Comment: "There are just classic ASP pages in the application?"  - This is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/04/tip-trick-integrating-asp-net-security-with-classic-asp-and-non-asp-net-urls.aspx

Comment: Are you aware of similar instructions for IIS 7?

Comment: @theycallmemorty: technically seaking, you can skip everything right up until the part that starts "Enabling Forms Authentication and Url Authorization for non-ASP.NET resources"

Comment: doesn't seem to work unfortunately.  I even created a simple html page in the root of the server and specifically 'denied' it in the web.config.

Comment: @theycallmemorty: You know that .html pages don't go through the asp.net runtime.. right?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to embed the pages in an ASP.NET page using Server.Execute. This approach should allow you to incorporate authentication into the legacy ASP pages.